# UIScrollView Autolayout height not setting on dynamic content

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have two labels that are inside a stack view that is encapsulated in a scroll view. The layout structure is like the following:

[image]

The layout looks like so in the interface builder. (This is the view with the `contentView` selected)

The `Content Stack View` is pinned to the `contentView`'s via `top, leading, trailing` with 8pt on each.

[image]

The `labels` are set at runtime and can be quite tall. This cuts off the text and causes the scroll view to not be scrollable. (Cuts off at bottom)

[image]

I've went through a few other similar questions on here but was unable to find a solution to mine.

Some are resources I went through I looked at were [Mokagio](http://mokagio.github.io/tech-journal/2015/06/24/ios-scroll-view-and-interface-builder.html), and [Natasha](https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/).

I have been on this for over a day now and am completely stumped.

How does the `Scroll View`'s content size become scrollable from the generated content?

Comment: you have to find label text height & give that height to contentsize of scrollview

Answer (score 2):

Please follow below steps:

1. Add `UIView` into `UIScrollView` and then add both `UILabel` into `UIView`.
2. Set top, bottom, leading, trailing constraints to `UIScrollView` and `UIView`
3. For both `UILabel` set top, leading, trailing, bottom, width, and height constraints.
4. lastly edit `height` constraints to set -  `priority High(750)`, select `>=` from constants dropdown for both `UILabel`

**IMPORTANT**: set `UILabel's number of lines to 0`

Please see below screenshot for `UIlabel` constraints:

[image: UIlabel constraints]